# Changing an attribute to be no longer transient - can I do this with lightweight Core Data migration?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, core-data-migration

From what I've read, lightweight migration in Core Data can be done in any of the following circumstances:

- Add an entity
- Remove an entity
- Rename an entity
- Add an attribute / relationship
- Remove an attribute / relationship
- Rename an attribute / relationship
- Make an attribute / relationship optional
- Make an attribute / relationship not optional, but provide a default value!

But I don't see how making an entity no longer transient fits into that. Do I need to do an advanced migration? Do I need to migrate at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transient properties are basically ignored by the versioning system, so changing a transient property to an persistent attribute should be the same as adding an attribute which a lightweight migration will be sufficient for.

Answer inferred from the second part of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734189/when-should-transient-properties-in-coredata-be-included-in-the-object-model).